# Why am i getting rank error when trying to .Q.dpft?

Tags: kdb

I created a new HDB only kdb and have a script that is to populate data in the tables.

```
func{[]
     var1:<some logic that calls other functions and brings back results>;
     var2:<same as above>;
     saveToDB[var1;var2];
  };

saveToDB{[var1;var2]

        path:`$":/path/to/db";
        tableName1:var1;
        tableName2:var2;

        show "saving table1";
        .Q.dpft[path;.z.d;`sym;`tableName1];
        show "saving table2";
        .Q.dpft[path;.z.d;`sym;`tableName2]; 
  };
```

What am i doing wrong here? I do see the first show string in logs and then it errors out.
I do get results into the variables var1 and var2. I am calling func[].

P.S I tried making tableName1 and tableName2 globals but still having the same issue.

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: _"it errors out"_ So, why didn't you quote the full error in your post?

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest running the function and add a break at the beginning of saveToDB and see how `var1` and `var2` looks like. It might be an issue caused by the format of the tables. You can also check that in the beginning of your `saveToDB` function by including this line.

i.e

```
if[any 98<>type each(var1;var2);:-1"ERROR: not tables"];
```

If tables are ok try replacing

```
tableName1:var1;
tableName2:var2;

`tableName1 set var1;
`tableName2 set var2;

[...other code...]
delete tableName1,tableName2 from `.;
```

I would also suggest using `-1` instead of `show` if you are using logs as it is common practice to redirect output from the command line.

You can also opt for a different method of saving tables down. For example using `.Q.en` to enumerate columns (if necessary) and use `.Q.par` to save the tables down as splayed tables.

Comment: .Q.par doesn't save data as a splayed table. 'set' the function which is used to splay data. 
.Q.par returns the location of a partition in a partitioned database.

Comment: I believe Alex meant to use .Q.par along with set for saving down the table splayed. Something like the following code: ```(`$(string .Q.par[`:.;.z.d;`tablename1]),"/") set .Q.en[`:.]tablename1```